# where is CLLocationDegrees in MonoTouch?

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, core-location, xamarin

I just gave try to MonoTouch an wondering about that [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) seems to be implemented, but not `CLLocationDegrees`. Is there a .net replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationDegrees` is simply a `double`, see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html).

In Xamarin.iOS we directly use the `System.Double` type so you can use any provided `System.Math` methods, 3rd party math code, extensions methods... without having to (even implicitly) typecast the values.